# Convert special String into Date in H2

Tags: sql, oracle, h2, sql-timestamp

There is a SQL function from Oracle `to_date('26 Jul 2016, 05:15:58 AM','DD Mon YYYY, HH:MI:SS AM')`, and it throws exception "Illegal pattern character 'o'" in H2.

How shall I change it to make it work in H2?

Comment: I don't know the platform, but is `Mon` the way you declare a month in that context? I'd bet not - I'd bet it's `MM`

Comment: Yes, Mon is format from Oracle.

Comment: @Pekka웃: `Mon` is the format pattern for the abbreviated month name in Oracle (e.g. `Feb` or `Jul`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equivalent function of `TO_DATE()` in H2 is `PARSEDATETIME()`.

This is how you should use it with your sample data:

```
PARSEDATETIME('26 Jul 2016, 05:15:58 AM','dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss a','en')
```

Be careful not to use `HH:mm:ss` otherwise the AM/PM detection will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, integrating milliseconds:

The original value in Oracle is `13-APR-17 10.49.36.558000000 PM`. First you need to get rid of the extra zeros and end up with `13-APR-17 10.49.36.558 PM` then you can call

```
call PARSEDATETIME('13-APR-17 10.49.36.558000000 PM','dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a','en');
```

Note the additional format parameter `.SSS`
[image]